# Trouble importing VTK files into Paraview (Error reading ascii data)

Tags: vtk, paraview

I am very new to using Paraview, and I'm trying [to import a few VTK files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h1grtr44m2muoxi/AACvsXpSx0dilOXtbMXqxQNua?dl=0) and view them. However, I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Generic Warning: In /Users/kitware/dashboards/buildbot-slave/8275bd07/build/superbuild/paraview/src/VTK/IO/Legacy/vtkDataReader.cxx, line 1436
Error reading ascii data. Possible mismatch of datasize with declaration.

ERROR: In /Users/kitware/dashboards/buildbot-slave/8275bd07/build/superbuild/paraview/src/VTK/IO/Legacy/vtkUnstructuredGridReader.cxx, line 346
vtkUnstructuredGridReader (0x7fb15582bd10): Unrecognized keyword: ,
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, I've tried converting them to other formats to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a problem with the files. I can open them with Paraview 5.6. Maybe they were generated with a version of VTK that is more recent than the one used for your version of Paraview. You should install the latest version of Paraview (or at least 5.6).

The big file results in some visible geometry, the smaller one does not. But I have no error message, everything seems ok.